# RStudio session crashes on running nloptr

Tags: r, rstudio, crash-reports

I am trying to run a non-linear constrained optimisation using the nloptr package. When I run the optimisation the Rstudio session crashes. The log files don't seem to capture this crash. The last log file is from some weeks back. The diagnostics report also shows this as the last error:

> 31 Jul 2021 12:49:50 [rsession-dhruvakaggarwal] ERROR system error 2
> (No such file or directory)
> [path=/Volumes/GoogleDrive/.shortcut-targets-by-id/1uELoLTtQ0-MVlZj5loA1k2gZAdJlDODV/SEA-LBL/Dhruvak];
> OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error
> rstudio::core::FilePath::makeCurrentPath(bool) const
> /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/core/FilePath.cpp:1037; LOGGED FROM:
> virtual void
> rstudio::session::modules::rmarkdown::notebook::ChunkExecContext::connect()
> /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/modules/rmarkdown/NotebookExec.cpp:202

When I request logs it shows this:

[image]

The session does not crash when the optimisation problem is run on a substantially smaller sample dataset, which might point to limited RAM on the system? I'm running it on an 8GB system, but I've tried it on a 32GB system and it still crashes. Curiously, it doesn't crash on another 16GB system.

**Session info:**

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.16

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7       compiler_4.0.0   pillar_1.6.2     bitops_1.0-6     tools_4.0.0      lifecycle_1.0.0  tibble_3.0.1    
 [8] gtable_0.3.0     lattice_0.20-41  pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.11     Matrix_1.2-18    cli_2.0.2        DBI_1.1.0       
[15] rstudioapi_0.11  binman_0.1.1     dplyr_1.0.7      generics_0.0.2   vctrs_0.3.8      askpass_1.1      mitools_2.4     
[22] caTools_1.18.0   tidyselect_1.1.0 grid_4.0.0       glue_1.4.0       R6_2.4.1         processx_3.4.2   fansi_0.4.1     
[29] XML_3.99-0.3     survival_3.1-12  RSelenium_1.7.7  purrr_0.3.4      ggplot2_3.3.0    semver_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5    
[36] ps_1.3.2         scales_1.1.0     ellipsis_0.3.2   splines_4.0.0    assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 utf8_1.1.4      
[43] survey_4.0       openssl_1.4.1    munsell_0.5.0    wdman_0.2.5      crayon_1.3.4
```

**I am unable to figure out the cause for this. Please help.**

Comment: Does it crash when you run it out of RStudio?

Comment: Not sure how to do that? I've only tried running it on RStudio on different systems.